# How can I do a variable for meta_query?

Tags: custom-field, meta-query

I have a code which needs a variable compare string

```
array(
        'key' => 'rob_value',
        'value' => $rob,
        'compare' => '='   
     )
```

the compare `=>'=`' needs to be `'='` to get values according a variable data from search form, but sometimes the value is null (empty) and the compare line needs to change to compare `=>'!='`

I have tested changing the code manually and it works perfectly. Now I want to do the code change according the values on search form.

Comment: where is problem?

Comment: @Alexey
the compare line now is '=',and I need the line changes automatically to '!=' value.... something like if $rob="" then $rob_comp="!=" else $rob_comp="=" then we got to array to use 'compare'=>$rob_comp instead '=' or '!=' only.

Comment: Just change it! I don't see a problem. How can I help you?

Comment: I found the anwser to my last 3 questions the meta_query works perfect!

first I need to do this:

php if($rob != '') { $rob_comp= '='; } else { $rob_comp= '!='; }

then change the code for array
array( 'key' => 'rob_value', 'value' => $rob, 'compare' => $rob_comp
)

Doing this works for more than 2 meta_query with no need to do a wpdb=>query

Comment: Please add this as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Use a ternary operation to keep it trim.

```
array(
    'key' => 'rob_value', 
    'value' => $rob, 
    'compare' => ( empty( $rob ) ? '!=' : '=' )
);
```

Breakdown, incase you've not seen ternary operators before..

```
array(
    'key' => 'rob_value', 
    'value' => $rob, 
    'compare' => ( 
        // If
        empty( $rob ) 
        // Then
        ? '!=' 
        // Else
        : '=' 
    )
);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

**FYI:** This question should ideally have been on StackOverflow, it's more centric to general PHP(if/else/comparison) than to WordPress(you just happening to be writing code for WordPress).

All the same, hope that helps..

Comment: thanks for this example, I wrote the if operators outside the query to use an extra $string... but this code is easier to follow. This also helps to close this answer, Thanks to all!

Comment: @FernandoBaltazar please come back and **accept this answer** if it solves your problem.